# How to send values to crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to print the values on crystal report that user input on the asp.net webform. On my form i have few textboxes, radio button list and couple of gridviews. Im not sure how to send these values to crystal report? Im using asp.net 3.5 and .Net builtin crystal reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass values to Crystal Reports via parameters.

[Here is an example how](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Working-with-Parameters-with-Crystal-Reports-and-ASP-NET-2-0/). It is somewhat dated, by CR doesn't really change all that quickly.

Comment: This shows me sending parameter to a report but i also want to display my gridview records on report and that gridview data is not stored in database